# Syntax error for @ sign in XQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

Im attempting to perform a basic query against some XML in an XML typed SQL Server 2008 field.

```
select OrderId, ProfileXML.query('/IntegrationMessage
                                    /Registrant
                                      [EktronUsername
                                       = TESTER2@QAI.COM]') from OrderDetails
```

If I execute the query above, I get the error message:

> Syntax error near '@', expected ']'

Do I need to escape my @ sign for the email address?  I tried using "@@" in the email address, but that didnt seem to help at all.

Thanks

Comment: double quotes did it, thanks marc_s!  Can you please repost your suggesstion as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Done - you got your answer ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to put double quotes around your value in the XPath:

```
'/IntegrationMessage/Registrant[EktronUsername="TESTER2@QAI.COM"]') 
                                               *               *
```

That way the content will not be interpreted as anything but a simple value.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Explanation: literal strings must be enclosed with quotes. Otherwise, XPath expression parser would begin to parse an expression until finding that `@` can't be part of a QName